Which non-unital $C^*$-algebras contain the *ortho-complements* of each of its projections?
Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a complex Hilbert space and $E$ is a projection in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Then $E^\perp:=I_{\mathcal{H}} - E$ is the largest projection such that $EE^\perp = E^\perp E=0$. My question is what happens in a non-unital $C^*$-algebra:

Question 1. Suppose $\mathfrak{A}$ is a non-unital $C^*$-aglebra and $E\in \mathfrak{A}$ is a projection (i.e., $E^*=E^2=E$). Does there always exist a projection $F\in \mathfrak{A}$ such that $EF = 0= FE$? If so then does there exist a largest one among them so that we can call that $F$ to be $E^\perp$ in some sense?

I think the first question may be true. For example if $\xi \in \mathcal{H}$ be an unit vector then the rank one projection $E_{\xi}$ belongs to the $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$, compact operators. If we take any vector $\eta$ with $\langle \eta, \xi\rangle=0$ then $E_\xi E_\eta = 0$. Though this doesn't prove the first question!

Question 2. If the answer to the Question 1 is false then what are those $C^*$-algebras where every projection has its orthogonal complement inside the algebra? unital algebras are definitely such an algebras, what about others such as monotone $\sigma$-complete $C^*$-algebras?

Thanks for your help.

I think that instead of "smallest" you are thinking of "biggest", otherwise surely $0$ or a projection onto a smaller subset of the orthocomplement of the range would be the orthocomplement of your projection, I think so anyway?

Unless you count $F=0$, the first question has a negative answer. For example, $\mathbb{C}\oplus A$ where $A$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra with no nonzero projection (say, $A=C_0(\mathbb{R})$) has a nonzero projection, namely $(1,0)$, with no nonzero projection orthogonal to it.

To expand slightly upon David's comment, even when there are nonzero projections orthogonal to $E$, there need not be a largest one.  Consider $\mathfrak{A}=C_0(\mathbb{N})$, let $E$ be the projection whose first coordinate is $1$ with all other coordinates $0$.  Then there are infinitely many distinct projections orthogonal to $E$, none of which is maximal with respect to this property.

Also, let me note that either you allow situations as in my last comment, namely, there exists projection $p$ s.t. the only projection orthogonal to $p$ is $0$; or it must be the case no projection whatsoever can have a largest projection orthogonal to it. Indeed, if $q$ is the largest projection orthogonal to $p$, then $p+q$ is a projection s.t. the only projection orthogonal to $p+q$ is $0$.
